# How to show dates in Outlook email grouping headers

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to show dates in the group headers when grouping emails in Outlook? By 'date' I mean an actual date (like Oct 10, Dec 12 etc.), not a weekday (like Monday, Friday, Yesterday, Today etc.) By googling I only found information on how to turn grouping on or off, or how to change the date format of the emails itself, but nothing about this. This would be more useful info than weekday, because the emails' dates are shown on that list only if the list pane is made so wide that it takes all space from the preview pane. So if this is possible, how?

My Outlook is the one in Microsoft 365 apps (version 2110) in case it matters. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add the actual date in the group header as shown in the below figure?
[image]

If so, through my test and research, I'm afraid this cannot be customized. As i know, the group header depends on the condition you set "group by". Suppose that if you group by subject, the group headers will be displayed as subjects. If you group by date, messages will only be grouped by the default date in outlook, today, yesterday, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to customize. I'd like to see dates like Nov 16 etc. there instead of (or in addition to, whatever) today, yesterday etc. My research did not find anything either, that's why I asked. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I'm afraid the group header cannot be changed or set. If you really need this function, you might as well submit feedback in the outlook client(File>Feedback). Hope Microsoft will notice this in the future.